# what would the regular expression to extract the 3 from be?

Tags: ruby, regex

I basically need to get the bit after the last pipe

```
"3083505|07733366638|3"
```

What would the regular expression for this be?

Comment: For future reference, [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a great source for Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that most easily by using [String#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-rindex):

```
line = "3083505|07733366638|37"

line[line.rindex('|')+1..-1]
  #=> "37"
```

If you insist on using a regex:

```
r = /
    .*   # match any number of any character (greedily!)
    \|   # match pipe
    (.+) # match one or more characters in capture group 1
    /x   # extended mode

line[r,1]
  #=> "37"
```

Alternatively:

```
r = /
    .*   # match any number of any character (greedily!)
    \|   # match pipe
    \K   # forget everything matched so far
    .+   # match one or more characters
    /x   # extended mode

line[r]
  #=> "37"
```

or, as suggested by @engineersmnky in a comment on @shivam's answer:

```
r = /
    (?<=\|) # match a pipe in a positive lookbehind
    \d+     # match any number of digits
    \z      # match end of string
    /x      # extended mode

line[r]
  #=> "37"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this without regex. Here:

```
"3083505|07733366638|3".split("|").last
# => "3"
```

With regex: (assuming its always going to be integer values)

```
"3083505|07733366638|3".scan(/\|(\d+)$/)[0][0] # or use \w+ if you want to extract any word after `|`
# => "3"
```

Comment: you could also have a regex without capture groups just using a look behind like `/(?<=\|)\d+$/`

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex :

```
.*\|(.*)
```

It returns whatever comes after ***LAST |*** .

Comment: Your observation was used by both @glenn and me before you posted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for checking my ans . Of course i observed your answer and i figured out a simpler regex can also be generated so i created one using http://regex101.com/ link .

Answer (score 1):

I would use `split` and `last`, but you could do

```
last_field = line.sub(/.+\|/, "")
```

That remove all chars up to and including the last pipe.